# Can not sort month-year column?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a date column. I created Month-Year column in my report using the following expression, but I am not able to sort month-year wise.

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!new_sitevisiteddateutc.Value))& "-"& Year(Fields!new_sitevisiteddateutc.Value)
```

I would like to have `MAY-2009 JUNE-2009 JANUARY-2011 MARCH-2011`, however I am getting `JUNE-2009  MARCH-2011  MAY-2009  JANUARY-2011`.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

In the table properties you can add multiple sorting fields and thier order.

Sort by year first and then month.

1. =Year(Fields!new_sitevisiteddateutc.Value)
2. =Month(Fields!new_sitevisiteddateutc.Value)

[image]

Comment: New column is a Columngrou. I am using ssrs2008. Now tell me how to do this.

Comment: Do sorting on the while table not just the column. If you click on the border of the table then right click the top left of table you can set the sorting for the table.

Comment: In Column Group properties- i am sorting with date field now and I got the result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How else you gonna get that unsung hero badge? :P (I got ya, +1)